# Odoo custom form field widget - how to display field value?

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I've created a custom widget in Odoo, and display it for a form field.
My template looks like this:

```
<t t-name="ImageDisplayer">
    <img t-att-src="?"/>
</t>
```

How can I put the field's value into the `<img>` tag's `src` attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending a day digging in the source code, I've found the solution! It doesn't really involve the template, but I got the idea from the source code of default text field widget, so I think it shouldn't be considered as "hacking".

Here's my custom widget class:

```
openerp.mymodule = function(instance, local) {
    instance.ImageDisplayer = instance.web.form.AbstractField.extend({
        template: "ImageDisplayer",
        init: function (view, code) {
            this._super(view, code);
        },
        // The key part:
        render_value: function() {
            this.$el[0].src = this.get("value");
        }
    });
    instance.web.form.widgets.add('ImageDisplayer', 'instance.ImageDisplayer');
}
```

My template now does not contain anything special:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="ImageDisplayer">
        <img />
    </t>
</templates>
```

Works like a charm. It even updates the page whenever I do a change on server-side.

Odoo documentation should really be more talkative!!!

**Update:** the answer applies to Odoo 8. It may work slightly differently in Odoo 9, because they've revised the UI framework in the new version.

Answer (score 1):

We can do like that

```
<img t-att-src="kanban_image('model.name', 'image_small', record.id.value)"/>
```

Where

`model.name` is table name,

`image_small` is a field name which will hold/store binary type of data.

EDIT:

To display value of field in template, you may try with this

```
<img t-att-src="record.field_name"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I want to display an URL. The URL is the value of my field, and have no idea about how I could retrieve that value...

Comment: you may try with this `<img t-att-src="record.field_name"/> `

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try it tomorrow. I'm wondering how default textbox widget does it, as it works with any field of the model...